# Python3 Pandas Dataframe Split Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column on my dataframe that contains the following

```
Wal-Mart Stores, Inc., Clinton, IA 52732  
Benton Packing, LLC, Clearfield, UT 84016  
North Coast Iron Corp, Seattle, WA 98109  
Messer Construction Co. Inc., Amarillo, TX 79109  
Ocean Spray Cranberries, Inc., Henderson, NV  89011  
W R Derrick & Co.  Lexington, SC 29072
```

I am having problem to capture it using regex so far my regex works for first 2 lines:

```
[A-Z][A-za-z-\s]+,\s{1}(Inc.|LLC)
```

How do I split the column to 4 additional columns? i.e. Column1 = Company Name, Column 2 = City, Column 3 = State, Column 4 = Zipcode.

Example of the output is shown below:

```
Company_Name           City     State  ZipCode  
Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.  Clinton  IA     52732
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names are probably the trickiest part, but if you know that the structure of city, state, zip will always be the same (i.e. no extra commas) you could use [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to split the strings. Similarly pandas has a [`str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) method as well.

```
df
                                            Address
0          Wal-Mart Stores, Inc., Clinton, IA 52732
1         Benton Packing, LLC, Clearfield, UT 84016
2          North Coast Iron Corp, Seattle, WA 98109
3  Messer Construction Co. Inc., Amarillo, TX 79109

df['Zip'] = df.Address.map(lambda x: x.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1])
df['Name'], df['City'], df['State']= zip(*df.Address.map(lambda x: x.rsplit(' ', 1)[0].rsplit(',', 2)))

df
                                           Address    Zip  \
0           Wal-Mart Stores, Inc., Clinton, IA 5273   5273
1         Benton Packing, LLC, Clearfield, UT 84016  84016
2          North Coast Iron Corp, Seattle, WA 98109  98109
3  Messer Construction Co. Inc., Amarillo, TX 79109  79109

                           Name         City State
0         Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.      Clinton    IA
1           Benton Packing, LLC   Clearfield    UT
2         North Coast Iron Corp      Seattle    WA
3  Messer Construction Co. Inc.     Amarillo    TX
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As you mentioned, the name is the most tricky part. Can you give any suggestion how I can take care of these edge cases for name: 1. blahblah, Inc., City, State ZIP 2. blahblah, LLC, City, State ZIP 3. blahblah, LLC  City, State ZIP Thanks!